# Concatenar String Oracle en base a un length propuesto

Tags: oracle, plsql

Estoy experimentando en Oracle PLSQL un procedimiento del cual averiguo el length de un campo, y una vez obtenido hacer un UPDATE con concatenación de Strings y campos; siempre y cuando se adapten al máximo de caracteres del mismo.

Para mayor entendimiento, os muestro a continuación:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_NUEVOS_IDS IS 
s_num NUMBER;

length NUMBER;

cursor C1 is 
    SELECT x_docs, fecha_creacion
    FROM DOCS_ARCHIVO 
    WHERE ID_OFICIAL IS NULL
    AND ESTADO_DOC= 'F';
BEGIN
  s_num :=1;

  SELECT LENGTH(MAX(ID_OFICIAL))
  into length
  from DOCS_ARCHIVO
  WHERE ID_OFICIAL LIKE 'ES_7756%'; -- Resultado: 48


  FOR docu_rec in c1 
  LOOP 
        UPDATE DOCS_ARCHIVO
        SET ID_OFICIAL= 'ES_7756_' || TO_CHAR(docu_rec.fecha_creacion, 'YYYY') || '_PI0078' || LPAD(TO_CHAR(docu_rec.fecha_creacion, 'YYYY') || s_num, 17, '0')
        WHERE x_docs = docu_rec.x_docs;

        COMMIT;

        s_num := s_num + 1;

   END LOOP;
END P_NUEVOS_IDS;
```

-- Lo que quiero lograr: 'ES_7756_2023_PI007800000000000000000202301'

Mi consulta es: cómo comprobar que el nuevo identificador que se concatena para el update cumpla con el tamaño consultado, y evitar de esta forma la violación de la restricción (valor único)?

Añadiendo, tiene que ser en consecutivo, como si de una entidad débil se tratase.

Se agradece toda solución posible :)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr

Comment: ¿violación de cuál restricción exactamente?

Comment: Editado, @Japv, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, @jachguate, quiero evitar la restricción por PRIMARY_KEY_ID, al estilo de Entidad Débil.

Comment: Verificá que el ID no exista actualmente antes de actualizar tu registro. ¿Qué tiene que ver eso con la longitud del campo?

Comment: y que obtienes actualmente? cual es el error?

Comment: ¿qué significa _"que cumpla con el tamaño consultado"_?

Comment: Hola, @padaleiana. A lo mejor es lo que ando buscando :P Serías tan amable de dejar en respuesta, por favor? Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Es que en realidad esa no era una respuesta; aparte allí te hice otra pregunta, y los demás también te han hecho preguntas :(

Comment: Que cumpla con el valor consultado, @jachguate, que sea igual a 48

Comment: Hola, Bryro, muy buenas tardes! Obtengo esto: ES_7756_2023_PI007800000000000000000202301 Y no sé si con el LENGTH(MAX(ID_OFICIAL)) evito el error de restricción única. Muchas gracias y disculpa la demora. :)

Comment: Si siempre es 48, por qué enredar tanto la pregunta, dale a [edit] la pregunta y coloca directamente esa información en ella.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el feedback, @jachguate; pero he puesto esa información en la parte del código. Y ya que me has molestado, a partir de hoy me doy de baja en la comunidad. Muchas gracias por todo y muy buena suerte, sin rencores :)